# getting data from JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to isolate several variables from a JSON file I have taken from [https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?q='s-Hertogenbosch&days=3&alerts=yes&aqi=yes&key=X](https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?q=%27s-Hertogenbosch&days=3&alerts=yes&aqi=yes&key=X)

Key removed for safety reasons.

Therefore I use the following code:

```
import json

response = urlopen(url)
  
weer_data = json.loads(response.read())

location = weer_data['location']['name']
temp_current = weer_data['current']['temp_c']

alert_source = list(weer_data['alerts']['alert']['headline'])
```

location and temp_current can be isolated and stored as variable without any problem. But the alert_source gives me problems because there are multiple values with the same header 'headline' in the JSON file. The part that gives problems looks like this:

```
"alerts": {
    "alert": [
      {
        "headline": "Koninklijk Meteorologisch Instituut van België",
        "msgtype": "",
      },
      {
        "headline": "Deutscher Wetterdienst",
        "msgtype": "",
```

Anyone who can help me with storing the 'headline' as variable?

Comment: `list(alert['headline'] for alert in weer_data['alerts'])` or `weer_data['alert']` depending on what key is really in json

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: The expected result should be an dictonary with headline and msgtype for later use in an  e-mail. Like: Deascher Wetterdienst gives warning X

Comment: This question doesn't really have anything to do with JSON. You've already successfully done the only JSON-related part of this question: you used `json.loads` to *parse* the JSON into a Python `dict`. Everything else is just normal Python data structure access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
    "alert": [{
        "headline": "Koninklijk Meteorologisch Instituut van België",
        "msgtype": "",
    }, {
        "headline": "Deutscher Wetterdienst",
        "msgtype": "",
    }]
}

# if you want to get only first headline
print(weer_data["alert"][0]["headline"])

# get all the headline and store it in a list
headlines = [item["headline"] for item in weer_data["alert"]]
print(headlines)
```

Try this code, I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dict comprehension.

```
alert_source = {a['headline'] : a['msgtype'] for a in weer_data['alerts']['alert']}
```